# Dereferencing pointer to incomplete type (Node)

Tags: c, nodes

So I have a main C file with a header file with the declaration of a Node struct, but the Node struct is defined in another source C file.

When I tried accessing the data of one of the Node structs it gives me this error

Dereferencing pointer to incomplete type (Node).

when I put the definition in the header file or I put the definition in the main c file my program runs smoothly.

I honestly do not understand what the issue is.

Comment: Yep, that’s how it works. Consider that you could compile one C file at a time without the other one even being present.

Comment: To dereference a structure, the complete type must be visible.  When it isn't visible, it's an opaque type.  That's good for information hiding but means you need accessor functions to get at the internals of the structure.

Comment: so does this mean that it is impossible for me to access the value of the node unless i define the class in main or the header ?

Comment: No, as previously mentioned, you could use an accessor, a function whose purpose is to do exactly that. This function would be located in the "other C file" so it can dereference the pointer.

Answer (score 2):

So you have some kind of pointer to a struct.

```c
struct StructType *struct_ptr = ...;
```

And you haven't first declared `struct StructType`. That's no problem. The language allows this. By making sure that all pointers to structs are the same size regardless of the struct, the compiler can copy them around without problem.

But then you try to dereference the pointer.

```c
struct_ptr->field
```

If the compiler isn't told the type of `field`, it doesn't know how large it is, or how to interpret its constituent bytes. The compiler can't generate code to read the field or write to it without this information.

If the compiler isn't told which fields precede `field` in the struct and their types, it can't calculate the offset of `field` within the struct. That means it doesn't know where `field` is located within the struct. The compiler can't generate code to read the field or write to it without this information.

In your scenario, the compiler isn't told any of this information. These are the issues that prevent the compiler from compiling this code.